# How to publish a windows application and only get .exe files?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

When i publish my application i get these types of files [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFSIS.png), but other applications look like this [without deploy extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uppt8.png) I only want `exe` files and `dlls` and `paks` like a standard application has not `.deploy` files. Do i just remove them?

I've tried changing the config manager from debug to release but it still does the same thing.

Comment: That's probably the old school ClickOnce deployment, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019 But what you really should do is migrate to .NET Core 3.1 and then publish a single executable, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you publish the application via ClickOnce, you will use "setup.exe" to install the application, rather than the exe you mentioned.

If you want to remove the `.deploy` file extension, you can uncheck `Use ".deploy" file extension` by the following steps.

[image]

Comment: @DanielD If this answer helps you, please click `√` to mark it as an answer.